# Pop up shows from Google search redirext

Tags: wordpress, themes, web-hosting

My website shows a pop up notification only when the visit comes only from Google and when I click on any link on website it redirects to another website  shows from :
https://yallacoupondeals.com/

Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem were 3 files injected through the theme and plugin folders they were :

class.themes-modules.php

admin_ips.txt

monit.php

and also deleting this code in the head of functions.php file:

```
<?php if (file_exists(dirname(FILE) . '/class.theme-modules.php')) 
include_once(dirname(FILE) . '/class.theme-modules.php'); ?>
```